# sourcebans.smx Database failure: Could not find driver "mysql"

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine, sourcemod

Hi I've been going at this for literally hours now.

I've currently running my game server on a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04 x64).

This is where I currently am.

-Meta mod 1.10
-Sourcemod 1.5.4-git4078.tar.gz
-SourceBans 1.4.11

I've successfully completed the web installation. Although i am having trouble getting the game server to contact the webserver.

This is the output of the log.

```
L 06/12/2014 - 09:29:02: [sourcebans.smx] Database failure: Could not find driver "mysql". See FAQ: http://www.sourcebans.net/node/20
```

That link is dead not very usefull.
Some people say to install apt-get install lib32z1 which I did (Do i need to configure it anyway?) which **did not work** unfortunatly.

From the VPS I did manage to connect to my external mysql database using the mysql installed.

Is there anything else I should do?

My databases file. I
[image]

Comment: Not sure if this might cause a conflict with cs-go but MySQL and SQLite are two different database systems.

Answer (score 4):

This means the `mysql` extension is not running correctly.  Check that the following file exists:

```
addons/sourcemod/extensions/dbi.mysql.ext.so
```

If it does, make sure it has execute-permissions (`chmod u+x dbi.mysql.ext.so`).

---

If that doesn't help, the next most common problem *(from [this thread](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=71005))* seems to be missing the 32-bit zlib library.  Try [installing it](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/diag/missinglibz) on your system:

**32-bit Debian or Ubuntu:** `apt-get install zlib1g`
**64-bit Debian or Ubuntu:** `apt-get install lib32z1`
**32/64-bit Fedora:** `yum install zlib.i686`
**32/64-bit Mandriva:** `urpmi zlib1`
**32-bit SUSE:** `zypper install libz1`
**64-bit SUSE:** `zypper install libz1-32bit`

If that doesn't work, try running `ldd -d -r dbi.mysql.ext.so` to search for missing dependencies, then google how to install the appropriate dependency for your system.

Comment: Hi thanks for you're help. Those first two steps did not work unfortunately. When I ran ldd -d -r dbi.mysql.ext.so this is the output. Sorry I don't really understand it, is there something here which I need to fix? http://i.imgur.com/LIsstxr.png

Comment: @jackdh That looks fine to me.  I'm afraid I can't help you then.  I suggest you post your issue [here](https://forums.alliedmods.net/forumdisplay.php?f=58) - someone there should be able to help.

Comment: Could I ask do I need anything else from LAMP? as I only installed Mysql

Comment: No, you should only need MySQL.  If you can access it from the VPS I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Anyway BlueRaja thank you so much for you're quick support I really appreciate it! - Last thing, the werid was when I had the webserver on the same box as the game it worked fine